# How can I check if a character is allowed to be uploaded in Teradata?

Tags: character, teradata

How can I check if a character is allowed to be uploaded in Teradata ?

Recently I was uploading (using jdbc) a `.csv` file that contained some weird `SUB` characters. The upload failed. Later i found out that those weird characters were the older version of the `end of file` marker. So, where can I get a list of all allowed characters so that I could `pre clean` my csv files and be sure that they get uploaded ?

Thanks

Comment: Did your upload fail? It is possible to insert non-printable characters in LATIN or UNICODE defined columns.

Comment: It failed. But when I manually removed those weird characters, the upload succeded. I define ONLY UNICODE columns, as this is the best practice when using jdbc.

Comment: What was the error message returned? The easiest solution would be to scrub all non-printable characters from your incoming data file but if you are interested in retaining newline, carriage return, and hard tab data you have to accommodate that in your `pre clean`.

Comment: The error message was `unable to executeUpdate()`. I removed those non printable characters easily, and uploaded successfully. It's just I want to have filter that would automatically remove those characters. That's why I need a list of all "okay" characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the Teradata International Character Set Support documentation to explain why you are encountering the error with the `SUB` data in your. Which is what I believe the user `logic` linked to in his/her answer.

> The characters 0x1A in LATIN/KANJI1/KANJISJIS and U+FFFD in
>   UNICODE/GRAPHIC are used internally by Teradata as the error
>   character; therefore, they are unusable as user data. The user cannot
>   store or retrieve these values through Teradata.

The list of supported UNICODE characters can be found here: [UNICODE Server Character Set](http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=062280001) (direct download of text file)

Answer (score 1):

@Alex You could try looking here? :)

http://www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?txtrelno=&prodline=all&frmdt=&srtord=Asc&todt=&txtsrchstring=character&rdsort=Title&txtpid=

Update! The link leads to multiple lists of Teradata's supported characters

Comment: You should take a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer`. When providing a link as an answer you should provide some context about that link including relevant parts to the answer in the event that the link target becomes unavailable.